# Symmetric and antisymmetric representations of a finite group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, characters

Although this question is highly related to my past question, but I'd like to understand general theory of symmetric and antisymmetric reps. of a finite group so let me post this question.

As far as I know, the Kronecker (or direct product) representation is defined as follows;

Let ${\mathscr R}_{\alpha}$ and ${\mathscr R}_{\beta}$ are irreducible representations of a finite group ${\mathscr G}$. ${\mathscr R}_{\alpha, \beta}$ acts on vector spaces $V_{\alpha}, V_{\beta}$ by their representation matrices $M^{[\alpha, \beta]}(g)$, respectively.
I denote the basis of $V_{\alpha}, V_{\beta}$ by $\{\left|i\right\rangle\}$, $\{\left|s\right\rangle\}$ $(i = 1, 2, \dots, d_{\alpha}\equiv {\rm dim} {\mathscr R}_{\alpha}, j=1, 2, \dots, d_{\beta} )$.

Then the Kronecker representation ${\scr R}_{\alpha \times \beta}$ is the representation of ${\mathscr G}$ on the product space $V \otimes V$, which satisfies

\begin{align}
  \left|A\right\rangle &\rightarrow M^{[\alpha \times \beta ]}_{AB} \left|B\right\rangle \\
                       &\equiv M^{[\alpha]}_{ij} M^{[\beta]}_{st} \left|j\right\rangle \otimes \left|t\right\rangle,
\end{align}
where I suppressed the summation symbols.

Since the Kronecker representation is also a representation of $\scr{G}$, it can be decomposed into sum of irreducible representations. This can be done explicitly by calculation of Clebsch-Gordan coefficients.

Next, let us assume the case two irreducible representations are exactly same, ${\scr R}_{\alpha} = {\scr R}_{\beta}$.
Then the product space itself has two invariant subspaces under the group action, namely symmetric and antisymmetric product space. The basis of them are given by
\begin{align}
  \frac{1}{2} \left( \left|i\right\rangle \otimes \left|s\right\rangle + \left|s\right\rangle \otimes \left|j\right\rangle\right) ~~(i \leq s), \\
  \frac{1}{2} \left( \left|i\right\rangle \otimes \left|s\right\rangle - \left|s\right\rangle \otimes \left|j\right\rangle\right) ~~(i < s).
\end{align}
The dimension of spaces $S(V^2), \Lambda(V^2)$ spanned by these basis are $ \frac{d(d+1)}{2} $ and $ \frac{d(d-1)}{2} $, respectively($d = d_{\alpha} = d_{\beta}$).

**My question is: How can we determine the character of the Kronecker rep. which acts on the *symmetric* subspace** (i.e. the character of the symmetric product representation)?

Some textbooks states it is given by $\chi^{[\alpha \times \alpha]}_{[\rm sym]}(g) = \frac{1}{2} (\chi^2(g) + \chi(g^2))$, but I don't understand it now.

In fact, the derivation of this formula which I considered is; On the symmetric subspace $S^2(V)$, $\left|A \right\rangle$ takes the form of $\frac{1}{2} \left( \left|j\right\rangle \otimes \left|s\right\rangle + \left|s\right\rangle \otimes \left|t\right\rangle\right)$. Then $M^{[\alpha \times \alpha]}_{AB, {\rm [sym]}}$ should be defined as
\begin{align}
  \left|A\right\rangle &\rightarrow M^{[\alpha \times \alpha ]}_{AB} \left|B\right\rangle \\
                       &\equiv M^{[\alpha]}_{ij} M^{[\alpha]}_{st} \frac{1}{2} \left( \left|j\right\rangle \otimes \left|t\right\rangle + \left|t\right\rangle \otimes \left|j\right\rangle \right) \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \left( M^{[\alpha]}_{ij} M^{[\alpha]}_{st} + M^{[\alpha]}_{it} M^{[\alpha]}_{sj} \right)　\frac{1}{2} \left( \left|j\right\rangle \otimes \left|t\right\rangle + \left|t \right\rangle \otimes \left|j\right\rangle \right).
\end{align}
The last equality follows from the symmetry under $ j \leftrightarrow t$.

The character of $M^{[\alpha \times \alpha]}_{AB, {\rm [sym]}}$ is defined as
\begin{align}
\chi^{[\alpha \times \alpha]}_{\rm [sym]} (g) \equiv \sum_{A} M^{[\alpha \times \alpha]}_{AA, {\rm [sym]}}.
\end{align}

Then, in terms of the original irreducible reps., this quantity is expressed as
\begin{align}
\chi^{[\alpha \times \alpha]}_{\rm [sym]} (g) = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i \leq s} \left( M^{[\alpha]}_{ii} M^{[\alpha]}_{ss} + M^{[\alpha]}_{is} M^{[\alpha]}_{si} \right).
\end{align}

The point here is the fact that the summation region is $i \leq s$, not arbitrary. If we don't care about this constraint, then $S^2(V)$ has $d^2$ basis, but this is wrong I think.

However, the problem is that if we forget $i \leq s$ and calculate the summation for arbitrary $i, s$, we obtain the formula which I quoted.

Where was the mistake(s) in what I wrote?

Actually, I derived the term $M^{[\alpha]}_{is} M^{[\alpha]}_{si}$ *by hand* and this might mean $\chi^2(g) = \chi(g^2)$, which cannot be true in general so definitely I made a mistake somewhere.

Sorry for the long sentences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose the character on the original space is $\chi$.

Suppose the eigenvalues of $g$ on the original space are $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_d$.

Then the eigenvalues of $g^2$ on the original space are $\lambda_1^2,\dots,\lambda_d^2$.

Also the eigenvalues of $g$ on the symmetric square are $\lambda_1^2,\dots,\lambda_d^2$ and $\lambda_i \lambda_j$ for $1\leqslant i<j \leqslant d$.

So the character of $g$ on the symmetric square is
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{d}\lambda_i^2+ \sum_{1\leqslant i<j \leqslant d}\lambda_i\lambda_j
$$
and this sum is equal to
$$
\frac{1}{2}\left((\sum_{i=1}^{d}\lambda_i)^2 +\sum_{i=1}^{d}\lambda_i^2\right)
$$
which is just
$$
\frac{1}{2}\left(\chi(g)^2+\chi(g^2)\right).
$$

Comment: Exactly. I understand your answer but I have not found my mistake above... Anyway, thank you very much.

Comment: In this case, the original space and the symmetric space has different dimensions. Is this irrelevant to your discussion?

Comment: @Keyspire I don't follow. In your question you've got the dimensions $d$ and $\frac{d(d+1)}{2}$ just as my answer does.

Comment: Thank you, indeed now I found that I've made a mistake in a manner of taking the trace over $S^2(V)$. However, your simple derivation is very useful and instructive. Thank you!